# Raycast Not Working on Phone but working on Unity Editor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

When I run on unity editor, the raycast works perfectly. But when I run on mobile during "Build and Run" the ray cast don't hit anything. I know it doesn't hit anything because I placed a 3dtext to denote if there is a hot or not.

I have used the 3d text to compare the rays being produce in Unity editor and phone. They produce the same rays.

I have used this code before and it was doing fine. It works in unity editor but not on phone. Am I missing something?

I am using a Samsung S10 for testing.

```
            //Get input
            if (Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {

                if (!IsCurrentlyInTouch)
                {

                    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                    {
                        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                    }
                    else
                    {//keyboard
                        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                    }
                    
                    RaycastHit hit;
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity))
                    {
                        selectedObject = hit.transform;
                        //Do things
                    }



                    if (hit.collider != null)
                    {
                        DebugTxt.text = hit.collider.name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DebugTxt.text = "no hit " + ray.GetPoint(10) ;
                    }

                }
                IsCurrentlyInTouch = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsCurrentlyInTouch = false;
            }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Raycast is working fine on many devices but there is problem with samsung and xiami devices. Raycast is not working on devices like  samsung s10e, samsung galaxy s9+, samsung galaxy s7 edge, samsung galaxy s22+, samsung galaxy s9

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer from this youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFbrSa9qjbk&list=LL&index=1&ab_channel=unityfy

The problem was not in the code. It was when I switch to IL2CPP. For some reason raycast is affected when I switched to IL2CPP.

To solve, uncheck "Strip Engine Code" under Player Settings --> Other Settings --> Optimization

Comment: I can't see this option now. Now there is an option managed stripping level which is already disabled. Any other solution?